# PHP Mailer adds characters to text field

Tags: php, phpmailer

When PHP Mailer emails the inputted data, it adds a string of odd characters  - `&#13;&#10;` - for a line break.

For example when I enter into a textarea:

```
This is a test
2 pizzas
12 wings
```

It emails:

```
This is a test&#13;&#10;2 pizzas&#13;&#10;12 wings
```

Any idea what that's about? Below are the relevant snippets of code. Thanks!

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

if (!$mail->ValidateAddress($email)) {
    echo "Invalid Email Address";
    exit;
}

$email_body = "";
$email_body .= "Name " . $name . "\n";
$email_body .= "Email " . $email . "\n";
$email_body .= "Phone " . $email . "\n";
$email_body .= "Details " . $details . "\n";

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('amirm400@hotmail.com', 'Amir');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Offer request ' . $name;
$mail->Body    = $email_body;
```

And this

```
    <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) && $_GET["status"] == "thanks") {
        echo "<p>Thanks for your request! We&rsquo;ll be in touch with an offershortly!</p>";
    } else { ?>

    <form method="post" action="offer.php">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">  <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"> <br />
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"> <br />
        <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="22" rows="7"  placeholder="Description of Products: Include Model # and Condition"></textarea> <br />
        <input style="display:none" type="text" id="address" name="address" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Where does `$details` come from …? You are dealing with numeric character entities here, &#13;&#10; is the equivalent of \0d\0a, resp. \r\n. But, since you are sending your email as plain text, of course such HTML-specific stuff does not get interpreted.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. $details comes from the text area input.  I changed isHTML to true. That got rid of the character entities.  However now it's putting the submission on one line. Example:

This is a test <line break>
Line 2 <line break>
Line 3

Is emailed as:

This is a test Line 2 Line 3

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Well that because “line breaks” in HTML are done how …? By using `<br>` elements. (`nl2br` helps if you need to automatically “convert” them.)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old, buggy, and vulnerable version of PHPMailer, so you should [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) anyway. 6.0 has much more consistent handling of line breaks, which is what you're seeing here. Apart from that, you might have more luck using native PHP line breaks instead of literal newlines:

```
$email_body = "";
$email_body .= "Name " . $name . PHP_EOL;
$email_body .= "Email " . $email . PHP_EOL;
$email_body .= "Phone " . $email . PHP_EOL;
$email_body .= "Details " . $details . PHP_EOL;
```

Also, don't do this:

```
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
```

That's forgery and will result in your messages being blocked or spam filtered. Do this instead:

```
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->setFrom('amirm400@hotmail.com', 'Amir');
```

Comment: I made those adjustments except I have to ask the client if their server is on PHP 5.5 or later before I upgrade. Thanks!